# Complex potential in E227?

Tags: mathematical-physics, 18th-century, fluid-dynamics

I have a [reason to believe](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/14003/1800) that Euler introduced the complex potential in his [Continuation des recherches sur la theorie du mouvement does fluides](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/227/), published in 1757. However, I am having hard time recognizing where it appears. The relevant place seems to be here:

[image]

After establishing that $(u-iv)(dx+idy)$ and $(u+iv)(dx-idy)$ are integrable, he introduces functions $\phi$ and $\psi$. The problem is I am not sure what $\phi:(x+yi)$ means. Normally, I would expect the expression to involve some kind of derivative, such as
$$
(u-iv)(dx+idy) = d\phi + id\psi.
$$

I am hoping somebody could explain what is going on here.

If you need, Euler continues on the following page as:

[image]

Thanks!