# Who introduced the stream function?

Tags: complex-analysis, 18th-century, fluid-dynamics

I have found many different claimed answers to this question:

- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) on the stream function claims that Lagrange introduced it in 1781.
- Darrigol's [The Worlds of Flow](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tIRBzdTWwyUC&pg=PA163) says that D'Alambert [did it in 1761](https://fr.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=Page:D%27Alembert_-_Opuscules_math%C3%A9matiques,_Tome_1,_1761.djvu/159&action=edit&redlink=1).
- [The Oxford Handbook of the History of Physics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14002/who-introduced-velocity-potential/) mentions that Euler introduced the complex potential and so by extension the stream function [in 1757](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/227/) (p.356). However, [I am not sure](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14011/complex-potential-in-e227) if this claim is true.

Can somebody clarify this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is John Napier's 1614 invention of logarithms worth mentioning in this context? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 4):

d'Alembert did originally introduce the stream function in "Remarques sur les lois du mouvement des fluides" in 1761.  [Page 149](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/njp.32101037493978?urlappend=%3Bseq=171%3Bownerid=27021597769878015-183) says that

$$p = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \,,$$

$$q = - \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial z} \,,$$

where $q = -u$, $p = -v$, $z = y$, and $\omega = \psi$ in modern notation.  See page 138 for a better way to see how these variables match modern notation.  This is the stream function once you parse the odd notation.

Lagrange basically repeated this more clearly in 1781 in "Mémoire sur la théorie du mouvement des fluides".  See [page 173](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/nyp.33433009864657?urlappend=%3Bseq=235%3Bownerid=27021597769463683-297) in particular.  Lagrange changes the variables, though.  He gives

$$p = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} \,,$$

$$q = - \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \,,$$

where $p = u$, $q = v$, and $\omega = \psi$.  Other than that this is basically the modern notation for the stream function.

I'm not familiar with the history of the complex potential, so unfortunately I cannot help you there.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! My point was that if Euler really introduced the complex potential in 1757 it would mean that he also introduced the stream function, because it is just the imaginary part of the complex potential. It seems to me that one cannot really separate the history of the complex potential from the history of the stream function.